# Running a multilevel model without level-1 predictors

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis

Is it acceptable (publishable) to run a multilevel model with only level-2 and level-3 predictors? Example: Looking only at the effect of school resources, size or location, and at the district level (budget etc.). The dataset does not contain individual level variables (e.g. gender, SES etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's acceptable. Sometimes you don't have level 1 predictors. If you don't have them, you can't use them.